# Coldfusion Session Cookie

Tags: session, coldfusion, cookies

I am trying to delete the clientside session cookie when I access a certain page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean the CFID and CFTOKEN cookies? Or the Sessions struct? You can expire the cookies like this:

```
<cfcookie name="CFID" value="" expires="NOW" />
<cfcookie name="CFTOKEN" value="" expires="NOW" />
```

but if you want to clear the session scope you should do this:

```
<cfscript>
structClear(Session);
</cfscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the cookie again, with blank data and an expiry date of now.

```
<cfcookie name="cookie_name" value="" expires="now" />
```

It will remain for the rest of the request, and then it should go.

Answer (score 1):

See slide 34: http://slidesix.com/view/ColdFusion-Application-Security-The-Next-Step